# d3.js chart from json object

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, underscore.js

I'd like to create a simple pie chart in d3.js. The request response that I'm working with looks like this:

```
{"record":[{"status":"request"},{"status":"requirements"},{"status":"request"}]};
```

From what I've seen in examples, I need to convert that object to this:

```
[{"label":"Request", "value":2}, {"label":"Requirements", "value":1}];
```

I'm happy to use d3 functions or underscore or straight javascript to accomplish this, I just haven't been able to crack it on my own. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`d3.nest()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#-nest) to reformat your data:

```
var data = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d){ return d.status; })
    .rollup(function(leaves){ return leaves.length; })
    .entries(input.record)
    .map(function(d){ return {label: d.key, value: d.values}; });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply mdml! So using: 
var response = {"record":[{"status":"request"},{"status":"requirements"},{"status":"request"}]};
var data = d3.nest()
 .key(function(d){ return d.status; })
 .rollup(function(leaves){ return leaves.length; })
 .entries(response.record)
 .map(function(d){ return {label: d.key, value: d.values}; });
console.log(data);
I'm getting an error: "Unexpected value translate(NaN,NaN) parsing transform attribute"

Comment: Glad to help. So my answer reformatted your data correctly, but there's an issue using that data for your plot? I can't tell what's going on without  seeing your code. Maybe you can post another question with the code for your plot.

Comment: No, you nailed it. Stupid library error on my part. Thanks!!